# Create ..... When Overflow Occurs in Div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, html

I am using asp.net. i am trying to Insert data into the list view.My code smaple is like this:

```
     <ul class="toplistings">
                <asp:ListView ID="LatestRatingBusinessListView" runat="server">
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <div id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </div>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <h2>
                                <div style="height: 21px; padding: 3px;  word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;" >
                                    <a id="LatestRatingBusiness" href='<%#ResolveClientUrl("~/YellowPages/BusinessInstancePage.aspx?Menu=menu_cat_3594&bid=")+ Eval("BusinessID") %>'
                                        title="<%#Eval("BusinessName") %>" class="CategoryAndSubCategory">
                                        <%#Eval("BusinessName")%></a>
                                </div>
                            </h2>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
       </ul>
```

i have code behind like this:

```
  DataTable dt =  objYPReviewRatingDataAccess.GetLatestRatingOrderByOperationDate();
            LatestRatingBusinessListView.DataSource = dt;
            LatestRatingBusinessListView.DataBind();
```

in dt I have the Data like this

```
 BusinessID                  BusinessName
  000000001                  GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
  000000002                  abcd
  000000003                  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

and i am trying to display the BusinessName like This

```
  GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG...
  abcd
  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH...
```

I have no Idea of doing so I don't Want to Reject any of the character rather i just want to Show the Content with dot at the last when there is overflow.
How can i do this. Your Help means a lot to me.

Thank You

With Regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you can add the CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the objects you're talking about, which will add "..." to an overflowing text line before it's cut off.

Say you have a span:

```
<span class="testspan">Here's some text. Once the line becomes long enough, it will be cut off.</span>
```

With this CSS:

```
.testspan {
     text-decoration: none; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 20px;
}
```

You get this:

```
Here's some t...
```

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8a9gB/

Comment: Sir, do I have to place 'text-overflow:ellipsis' in the style attribute of div or i have to make a css of this. I have tried this in style atribute of div but it is not working.

Comment: can you post the styles as you're including them? Whenever possible, you should use a stylesheet rather than inline styles.